# Click add and removeclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have table which is like;

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>table 1 a <span class="icon"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>table 2 b <span class="icon"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>table 3 c <span class="icon"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and if I click row one my span class must be like this; `<span class="icon icon-active"></span>`

after that for example I click on row two my span class of two must be `<span class="icon icon-active"></span>` but span of row one (icon-active) must be removing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `removeClass()` and `addClass()` methods like following.

```js
$('table tr').click(function () {
    $('table .icon-active').removeClass('icon-active');
    $('.icon', this).addClass('icon-active');
})
```

```css
.icon-active {
    background-color: green;
}
.icon {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>table 1 a <span class="icon"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>table 2 b <span class="icon"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>table 3 c <span class="icon"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

With the use of removeClass() and addClass() methods of jquery. You can make it work.

1) first remove class from all span

2) add class to only one which is clicked

```js
$('tr').click(function(){

$('span').removeClass('icon-active');
$(this).find('span').addClass('icon-active');
});
```

```css
.icon-active {
  background-color:Blue !important;
  display:inline-block;
}

span.icon
{
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>table 1 a <span class="icon"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table 2 b <span class="icon"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table 3 c <span class="icon"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```